# Iframe 100% height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I created side panels for the client and the height of 100% in absolute position is not showing anything in the iframe. Below is the attached image of the iframe (id starts with ebDiv), the height has changed to 100% and it shows nothing. I am setting height to 920px to make it work but it should be 100% and if i change the position from fixed to absolute and height 100% then it works but 100% height is not showing in absolute position.

[Testing Page](http://www.smh.com.au/?adcall=true&adcallkw=MercedesParallaxTest&reload=true)

[image: Height 100% position absolute screenshot]

Comment: anyone can help please

Comment: Try to set innerHeight of window to iframe i.e $( window ).innerHeight(); and set it to iframe tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the window height and assign it to iframe.

Comment: window height just gives me the viewport height not the full page height. I am changing position from absolute to fixed at some point and absolute height is causing positioning issues